# Google analytics shows no hit on mobile.aspx of sitecore website

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics, sitecore, google-tag-manager

I am just testing google analytics on my sitecore website. After setting up everything i used below code to set on my main.aspx page.

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<noscript>
    <iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-TVSCV2" height="0" width="0" style="display: none; visibility: hidden"></iframe>
</noscript>
<script>
    (function(w, d, s, l, i) {
        w[l] = w[l] || [];
        w[l].push({
            'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),
            event: 'gtm.js'
        });
        var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            j = d.createElement(s),
            dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
        j.async = true;
        j.src =
            '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
        f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
    })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-TVSCV2');
</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Problem is that 'hits' on website working well with in case of 'main.aspx' but not working once I am going for 'mobile.aspx'. Hit counts remains '0' in case of mobile device.
Please suggest.

Comment: And `main.aspx` is the Layout file I presume? If you've added the above code directly in that file, and `mobile.aspx` is a separate Layout file used for a different device, then you'll need to include the code in that file too.

Comment: yes, I already added the  same code in mobile.aspx. It is self-explanatory but forgot to mention it over here.
And, yes they are both seperate layout file.

Comment: And you are certain the mobile device (the device with the Mobile layout) actually gets hit? How have you specified when to use Mobile?

Comment: Yes, I put some check in code to verify that site we are hitting is on mobile layout. Even while cross-checking the same on emulator I am getting properties of mobile device. We have specified it using sc_device property of sitecore. Overall, its certain that mobile layout is getting hit .